# Converting a sample rate of audio file iPhone

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, sample, avaudiorecorder, rate

I'd like to change the pitch of an audio file by changing the sample rate programmatically. I am recording the file using AVAudioRecorder. I have noticed a settings parameter within AVAudioPlayer, however, it is read only. Can anyone lend a helping hand? :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Answer (score 1):

You could manipulate the data the recording process returns, this is generally the way to go for DSP.
A simple change in sound's speed can be done with a resampling.

[Take a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28signal_processing%29)